# Booted up computer and bunch of random text

Tags: windows-10, boot, special-characters

So I have windows 10 on a desktop and when it was booted today, this is what was displayed. Does anyone have a clue? I wish I had more information on this, but this is all I have.

Thanks
[image: Error?!]

Comment: Told them too, I just got the results from them. It works now. Thanks for the reply! If you want to post it as the answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Ok, posted as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Video corruption, did you try a cold boot again?

Comment: Thanks for the comment/answer again! For anyone who encounters this issue, try a reboot as suggested by Moab!

Comment: Oh, out of curiosity would you mind briefly explaining how the video get corrupted? Like did BIOS mess up or something?

Comment: I have no clue, it quantum physics as why any computer can boot at all.